# jRuby ActiveRecord JDBC Adapter: connection_alive_sql with non JDBC-4.0-compliant Oracle driver?

Tags: oracle, activerecord, jdbc, jrubyonrails

I am trying to connect to a rather old Oracle DB with jRuby (on Rails) whose JDBC driver (release 8.0.5.0.0) is obviously not JDBC 4.0 compliant.

Rails/Rake suggests:

```
WARN: driver does not support checking if connection isValid() please make sure you're using a JDBC 4.0 compilant driver or set `connection_alive_sql: ...` in your database configuration
```

Question:

What kind of SQL statement should go in `connection_alive_sql`? Is this simply some arbitrary SQL like `SELECT SYSDATE from DUAL` or `SELECT COUNT(*) from MySchema.MyTable`? I do not find any further documentation about this option beside https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/wiki/Configuration.

**Update (after ibre5041's comment):**

After choosing `SELECT 1 from DUAL` for `connection_alive_sql`, at least the DB objects are created but the migration aborts nevertheless with:

```
== 20150618093004 CreateHospitals: migrating ==================================
-- create_table(:hospitals)
   -> 0.1050s
   -> 0 rows
== 20150618093004 CreateHospitals: migrated (0.1060s) =========================

rake aborted!
Java::JavaLang::AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdate(Ljava/lang/String;I)I
arjdbc.jdbc.RubyJdbcConnection$6.call(RubyJdbcConnection.java:675)
arjdbc.jdbc.RubyJdbcConnection$6.call(RubyJdbcConnection.java:669)
arjdbc.jdbc.RubyJdbcConnection.withConnection(RubyJdbcConnection.java:3228)
arjdbc.jdbc.RubyJdbcConnection.withConnection(RubyJdbcConnection.java:3209)
arjdbc.jdbc.RubyJdbcConnection.executeUpdate(RubyJdbcConnection.java:669)
arjdbc.jdbc.RubyJdbcConnection.execute_insert(RubyJdbcConnection.java:607)
arjdbc.jdbc.RubyJdbcConnection$INVOKER$i$execute_insert.call(RubyJdbcConnection$INVOKER$i$execute_insert.gen)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170)
org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.evalBlockBody(Interpreted19Block.java:206)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yield(Interpreted19Block.java:157)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yieldSpecific(Interpreted19Block.java:130)
org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:111)
org.jruby.ast.ZYieldNode.interpret(ZYieldNode.java:25)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.evalBlockBody(Interpreted19Block.java:206)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yield(Interpreted19Block.java:157)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yieldSpecific(Interpreted19Block.java:135)
org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:120)
org.jruby.ast.YieldOneNode.interpret(YieldOneNode.java:35)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221)
org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116)
org.jruby.ast.EnsureNode.interpret(EnsureNode.java:96)
org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:247)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:227)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:211)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:222)
org.jruby.ast.CallTwoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallTwoArgBlockNode.java:62)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221)
org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:247)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:227)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:356)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:213)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:222)
org.jruby.ast.FCallTwoArgBlockNode.interpret(FCallTwoArgBlockNode.java:34)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:118)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:290)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:243)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.cacheAndCall(SuperCallSite.java:406)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.callBlock(SuperCallSite.java:284)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.call(SuperCallSite.java:289)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.callVarargs(SuperCallSite.java:110)
org.jruby.ast.SuperNode.interpret(SuperNode.java:115)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:112)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:126)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:178)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:296)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:72)
org.jruby.ast.FCallManyArgsNode.interpret(FCallManyArgsNode.java:60)
org.jruby.ast.LocalAsgnNode.interpret(LocalAsgnNode.java:123)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:118)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:112)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:126)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:178)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:296)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:72)
org.jruby.ast.CallManyArgsNode.interpret(CallManyArgsNode.java:59)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:182)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:203)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170)
org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
org.jruby.ast.LocalAsgnNode.interpret(LocalAsgnNode.java:123)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:204)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:211)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.cacheAndCall(SuperCallSite.java:366)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.callBlock(SuperCallSite.java:192)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.call(SuperCallSite.java:197)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.callVarargs(SuperCallSite.java:108)
org.jruby.ast.SuperNode.interpret(SuperNode.java:115)
org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:116)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:195)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.cacheAndCall(SuperCallSite.java:346)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.callBlock(SuperCallSite.java:146)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.call(SuperCallSite.java:151)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.callVarargs(SuperCallSite.java:107)
org.jruby.ast.ZSuperNode.interpret(ZSuperNode.java:103)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.evalBlockBody(Interpreted19Block.java:206)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yield(Interpreted19Block.java:157)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yieldSpecific(Interpreted19Block.java:130)
org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:111)
org.jruby.ast.ZYieldNode.interpret(ZYieldNode.java:25)
org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:116)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:116)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:204)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:211)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:336)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:179)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:188)
org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgBlockNode.interpret(FCallOneArgBlockNode.java:34)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:195)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.cacheAndCall(SuperCallSite.java:346)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.callBlock(SuperCallSite.java:146)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.call(SuperCallSite.java:151)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.callVarargs(SuperCallSite.java:107)
org.jruby.ast.ZSuperNode.interpret(ZSuperNode.java:103)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:187)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136)
org.jruby.ast.VCallNode.interpret(VCallNode.java:88)
org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:116)
org.jruby.ast.LocalAsgnNode.interpret(LocalAsgnNode.java:123)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:195)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.cacheAndCall(SuperCallSite.java:346)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.callBlock(SuperCallSite.java:146)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.call(SuperCallSite.java:151)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.callVarargs(SuperCallSite.java:107)
org.jruby.ast.ZSuperNode.interpret(ZSuperNode.java:103)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.evalBlockBody(Interpreted19Block.java:206)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yield(Interpreted19Block.java:194)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.call(Interpreted19Block.java:125)
org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:101)
org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:290)
org.jruby.RubyProc.call19(RubyProc.java:271)
org.jruby.RubyProc$INVOKER$i$0$0$call19.call(RubyProc$INVOKER$i$0$0$call19.gen)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:202)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:198)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:134)
org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)
org.jruby.ast.OrNode.interpret(OrNode.java:100)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.AndNode.interpret(AndNode.java:97)
org.jruby.ast.AttrAssignOneArgNode.interpret(AttrAssignOneArgNode.java:33)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:182)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:203)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170)
org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
org.jruby.ast.DAsgnNode.interpret(DAsgnNode.java:110)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.evalBlockBody(Interpreted19Block.java:206)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yield(Interpreted19Block.java:194)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.call(Interpreted19Block.java:125)
org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:101)
org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:290)
org.jruby.RubyProc.call19(RubyProc.java:271)
org.jruby.RubyProc$INVOKER$i$0$0$call19.call(RubyProc$INVOKER$i$0$0$call19.gen)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:210)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:206)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:118)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:204)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:211)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:336)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:179)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:188)
org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgBlockNode.interpret(FCallOneArgBlockNode.java:34)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:187)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136)
org.jruby.ast.VCallNode.interpret(VCallNode.java:88)
org.jruby.ast.OrNode.interpret(OrNode.java:97)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:204)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:211)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.cacheAndCall(SuperCallSite.java:366)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.callBlock(SuperCallSite.java:192)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.call(SuperCallSite.java:197)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.callVarargs(SuperCallSite.java:108)
org.jruby.ast.ZSuperNode.interpret(ZSuperNode.java:103)
org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:116)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:195)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.cacheAndCall(SuperCallSite.java:346)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.callBlock(SuperCallSite.java:146)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.call(SuperCallSite.java:151)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.callVarargs(SuperCallSite.java:107)
org.jruby.ast.ZSuperNode.interpret(ZSuperNode.java:103)
org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:60)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:195)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.cacheAndCall(SuperCallSite.java:346)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.callBlock(SuperCallSite.java:146)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.call(SuperCallSite.java:151)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.callVarargs(SuperCallSite.java:107)
org.jruby.ast.ZSuperNode.interpret(ZSuperNode.java:103)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.evalBlockBody(Interpreted19Block.java:206)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yield(Interpreted19Block.java:157)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yieldSpecific(Interpreted19Block.java:130)
org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:111)
org.jruby.ast.ZYieldNode.interpret(ZYieldNode.java:25)
org.jruby.ast.LocalAsgnNode.interpret(LocalAsgnNode.java:123)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221)
org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116)
org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.evalBlockBody(Interpreted19Block.java:206)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yield(Interpreted19Block.java:157)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yieldSpecific(Interpreted19Block.java:130)
org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:111)
org.jruby.ast.ZYieldNode.interpret(ZYieldNode.java:25)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.evalBlockBody(Interpreted19Block.java:206)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yield(Interpreted19Block.java:157)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yieldSpecific(Interpreted19Block.java:130)
org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:111)
org.jruby.ast.ZYieldNode.interpret(ZYieldNode.java:25)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221)
org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116)
org.jruby.ast.EnsureNode.interpret(EnsureNode.java:96)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:204)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:211)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:336)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:179)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:188)
org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgBlockNode.interpret(FCallOneArgBlockNode.java:34)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:118)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221)
org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:204)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:211)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:336)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:179)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:183)
org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgBlockPassNode.interpret(CallOneArgBlockPassNode.java:60)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:195)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:316)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:145)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154)
org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:161)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:195)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:316)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:145)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154)
org.jruby.ast.FCallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(FCallNoArgBlockNode.java:32)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:187)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136)
org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:118)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:182)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:203)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170)
org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:118)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:182)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:203)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170)
org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgNode.interpret(FCallOneArgNode.java:36)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.evalBlockBody(Interpreted19Block.java:206)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yield(Interpreted19Block.java:157)
org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yieldSpecific(Interpreted19Block.java:130)
org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:111)
org.jruby.ast.ZYieldNode.interpret(ZYieldNode.java:25)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:118)
org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:204)
org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:211)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:336)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:179)
org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:188)
(... stripped the rest due to max. number of characters reached here ...)
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

**Update 2 (now with Oracle JDBC driver 9.2.0.8):**

With 9.2.0.8 rake still aborts, but "at least" throws an ORA error. In comparison to 8.0.5.0.0, no DB objects created inside the DB though (migration was based on a simple `rails g scaffold hospital name:string`, so no numbers involved here ... *??*):

```
rake --trace db:migrate
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
Java::JavaSql::SQLException: ORA-01722: invalid number
(...)
```

Comment: How old is that database(release)? Would ojdbc5.jar file from 10g/11g database work? Of course you can use statement like `select 1 from dual`.

Comment: Errm ... I know that's quite embarrassing, but it's a historic 8.0.5.0.0 release. Using it's original JDBC driver CLASSES1.ZIP.

Comment: AFAIK Oracle guarantees comparability at least  with one major release. At this moment I do not remember what drivers were shipped with 9i database but I think best you can do is to use driver from Oracle ver. 9.2.0.8 (Early 8i JDBC driver were very buggy I would not trust them anyway).

Comment: Ok it looks it is still downloadable: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc9201-092698.html ojdbc14.jar is the driver you're looking for.

Comment: I'm afraid I con not help you more. I never used ruby. I also do not know which SQL statement failed and what are you trying to achieve. The ORA- error code highlights that you are trying to use some kind of implicit datatype conversion. Maybe from VARCHAR2 into NUMBER (but not necessarily). This errors also occurs when other datatype conversion fail.

Comment: No problem, thank's nevertheless. I already guessed that the attempt might be in vain.